# How to save the date and time when a Core Data object is created

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I want to save & retrieve the timestamp of when the note was created in Core Data

Please guide me on how I can do this.

Comment: If you followed the Core Data tutorial it shows you how.

Comment: can you give me some link .....have example of it.

Comment: Google is your friend - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: That link doesn't work anymore. Try this one: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html. Look under "Object Life-Cycle—Initialization and Deallocation"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make a Core Data entity called Note, give it an attribute called 
***timeStamp*** Set it to type ***Date***.

When creating a new Note assign it the current time:

```
[note setTimeStamp:[NSDate date]];
```

Persist the Note, that is it.

Comment: The problem is that you'll have to remember to do this every time you crate a new Note. awakeFromInsert is a better place for it

Answer (score 51):

You can have your custom NSManagedObject subclass set an attribute as soon as it's inserted in a context by overriding the `-awakeFromInsert` method:

```
@interface Person : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDate *creationDate; // modeled property
@end

@implementation Person
@dynamic creationDate; // modeled property

- (void)awakeFromInsert
{
    [super awakeFromInsert];

    self.creationDate = [NSDate date];
}
@end
```

Note that `creationDate` above is a modeled property of Core Data attribute type "date", so its accessor methods are generated automatically.  Be sure to set your entity's custom NSManagedObject class name appropriately as well.

Comment: I prefer this approach, especially since I made an abstract class with this property in it. That way all my models that use a created/modified value are automatically handled with very little code.

Comment: This is a better approach. Plus it's the one Apple recommends.

Comment: If you chose to create your NSManagedObject subclass with primitive values, then you'll have to do something like 

self.creationDate = [NSDAte timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

Comment: This approach is better, but I recommend adding some kind of check (like `if (self.creationDate == nil) { ... }`) to account for cases where `-awakeFromInsert` is called multiple times. Yes, you would think it's only called once, but it's called _once per managed object context_. So if you have nested contexts, you'll get your creation date updated multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

Just to keep this question up-to-date with Swift, in the `xcdatamodelid` click the entity you wish to create a default date. Under the Data Model Inspector change Codegen from "Class Definition" to "Manual/None":

[image]

Then from the menu bar click `Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass...` and create the two Swift classes: `Note+CoreDataClass.swift` and `Note+CoreDataProperties.swift`

Open the `Note+CoreDataClass.swift` file and add the following code:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Note)
public class Note: NSManagedObject {
    override public func awakeFromInsert() {
        super.awakeFromInsert()
        self.creationDate = Date() as NSDate
    }
}
```

Now the `creationDate` will get a default date of the current date/time.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `Note` entity with a `created` attribute?

Set the default value to `now()`

**Edit**

Be aware that setting `now()` as the default means it will use the build time, not the current time. If you want to set it properly - you need to use an NSManagedObject subclass.