# Default timestamp attribute in coredata?

Tags: ios, database, core-data, timestamp

I want to know when a certain object was added to CoreData.

Is there a default timestamp or lastModified attribute in CoreData that I can access? If yes, how can I do that.

Comment: There is no default timestamp, but you can create one by overriding `awakeFromInsert` as described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4590190/1187415.